# C++ Determine if class can use an object - text RPG game

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm facing with the following design problem:

TL;TD need to determine if Hero(class) can use specific object while there's many heroes implementations

I have 3 subclasses of the class Hero, each one of them can use specific items.

For Weapons.hpp i have Sword,Hammer,CrossBow, Bow ,Wand , Staff.

Warrior can use Sword or hammer
Archer can use CrossBow or bow
Wizard can use staff or wand

There's Hero base class:

```
class Hero: public Entity{

public:
    Hero(std::string name, Gender gender, double damage, Point2d* location);
    ~Hero();
    virtual void move(int x, int y);
    virtual void damage(Entity* other); // Override
    virtual bool use(Potion* _potion);
    virtual bool use(Weapon* _weapon) = 0;
    virtual bool use(ShieldArmor* _shieldArmor) = 0;
    virtual bool use(BodyArmor* _bodyArmor) = 0;

private:
    std::string name;
    Gender gender;
    Weapon* weapon;
    ShieldArmor* shield_armor;
    BodyArmor* body_armor;
};
```

And this is Weapon:

```
class Weapon: public Item{

public:
    Weapon(double damage, Point2d* location); 
    virtual ~Weapon();
    virtual double getDamage() const;
    virtual const Point2d* getLocation() const; 
    virtual const std::string toString() const;

private:
    Point2d* location;
    double damage; 
};
```

In the Game's main i need to determine if Hero *h can use specific item without down casting if possible.

so i could use it like:

```
Hero *h;
Weapon * i;
// do something assign values
h->use(i);
```

Comment: Fun fact: You don't need to use pointers for everything. It's often better if you avoid pointers in favour static allocation, containers, and references.

Comment: @user4581301 Map's input is dynamic. 
I need to determine all that after getting hero type from the map's input also the items around based on some input.

Comment: Hard to say the best way to solve your problem without knowing the weapon use rules. Using old school D&D as an example, you could have `class Class` contain a `std::set<weapontype> allowedWeapons` that listed all of the allowed weapon types and a `bool canUse(Weapon *)` method that returns true if the weapon's type is in the `set`.  `class Weapon` needs a `weapontype getType()` method to support this. So `class Cleric: public Class` would init `allowedWeapons({OneHandBlunt, TwoHandBlunt, ...})` and a `Hero` would `myclass->canUse(weapon)` before attacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simplified the example by removing everything that isn't necessary and generalized to the concept of `Item`. A weapon is a subclass of Item, as is a potion, a wand, a flux capacitor, whatever. The `use` method does whatever the `Item` does to `target`. A weapon will attempt to hit and damage `target`. A healing potion will heal `target`. A flux capacitor will either send `target` back in time or zap the expletive deleted out of them with 1.21 gigawatts.

But everything is seen through the lens of `Item`. The invoking classes doesn't know what the item is, does, or what it did to `target`. `target` doesn't even know what was used on it, they just feel the effects. Nobody knows nothin' about the other objects outside of a simple, generic interface.

```
class Item
{
public:
    enum types
    {
        whole lot of types go here.
        They are fairly broad categories, like knife, sword, two handed sword, 
        healing potion, wand, etc.
    };
    types getType()
    {
         return type;
    }
    virtual bool use(Entity * target) = 0;
private:
    types type;

};

class Hero: public Entity{

public:
    Hero(std::set<Item::type> & usable): usableItems(usable)
    ~Hero();
    bool use(Item* item,
             Entity * target)
    {
        // this is the magic. If the item's type is in the list of usable items,
        // the item is used on the target. They exact type of item or target
        // is not known. Polymorphism will take care of everything from here
        if (usableItems.find(item->getType()) != usableItems.end())
        {
            return item->use(target);
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    std::set<Item::type> & usableItems;
};
```

The point is the main classes are incredibly stupid. They simply provide a framework for much more detailed objects to do the detailed work. `VorpalSword` uses generic methods inherited from `Weapon` and `Item` to see if it hit `target`, not knowing that `target` is in fact a `HugeRedDragon` instance, and if it hit assigns damage and then does the specific things a `VorpalSword` does like checking for lopped off limbs.

And all Hero saw was `item->use(target)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dynamic_cast<>()` to determine the type of your Hero pointer, like so:

```
Hero *h;
Weapon * i;
// do something assign values
if(dynamic_cast<HeroSubClass> != nullptr)
    h->use(i);
```

where `HeroSubClass` is the particular subclass of `Hero` that you want to check for (`Warrior`, etc.). If your `Hero *` is not a pointer to an object of class `HeroSubClass`, `dynamic_cast` will return `nullptr`, if it is, it will return a `HeroSubClass *`.

Alternatively, you could just check the type of the `Weapon *` within `use()` for each HeroSubClass, and perhaps print out something like "Warrior cannot use Staff" if it's an object of the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` values to define weapon and hero's specific types.

```
enum class HERO_TYPE{
   WARRIOR,
   ARCHER,
   WIZARD
}

class Hero: public Entity{

public:
    Hero( std::string name, Gender gender, double damage, Point2d* location, HERO_TYPE type );
    ~Hero();
    virtual void move(int x, int y);
    virtual void damage(Entity* other); // Override
    virtual bool use(Potion* _potion);
    virtual bool use(Weapon* _weapon) = 0;
    virtual bool use(ShieldArmor* _shieldArmor) = 0;
    virtual bool use(BodyArmor* _bodyArmor) = 0;

private:
    std::string name;
    Gender gender;
    Weapon* weapon;
    ShieldArmor* shield_armor;
    BodyArmor* body_armor;
    HERO_TYPE type; //define in subclasses.
};
```

and do same for weapons.

```
enum class WEAPON_TYPE{
       SWORD,
       CROSSBOW,
       WAND
    }
class Weapon: public Item{

public:
    Weapon(double damage, Point2d* location, WEAPON_TYPE type); 
    virtual ~Weapon();
    virtual double getDamage() const;
    virtual const Point2d* getLocation() const; 
    virtual const std::string toString() const;
    WEAPON_TYPE get_type() { return this->type; }//getter

private:
    Point2d* location;
    double damage;
    WEAPON_TYPE type;
};
```

Now you can specify weapons for hero classes.

```
void Hero::use(Weapon *i){
   if(!checkWeapon(i->get_type())) return;

  //...code...

}

bool Hero::checkWeapon(WEAPON_TYPE t){
  switch(this->type){
     case HERO_TYPE::WARRIOR:{
        if(t == WEAPON_TYPE::SWORD)
            return true;
     }break;

     case HERO_TYPE::ARCHER:{
        if(t == WEAPON_TYPE::CROSSBOW)
            return true;
     }break;

     //..all cases..
  }

  return false;//no hero-weapon matching
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about using Visitor Pattern.

Something like:

```
Hero * h;
Item * i;
Visitor v;
// Assign some values
h.accept(v,i);
```

Then the visitor looks like:

```
visit(sword *p, warrior * w){
    w.use(p);
}
visit(wand *p, wizard * w){
    w.use(p);
}
visit(bow *p, archer * w){
    w.use(p);
}
```

Any suggestions regard to this idea?

Comment: Forces the code to know what the `Hero` and the weapons are, putting you right back into having to cast. Workable, but not a particularly good solution.