# RPG Game inventory system

Tags: c++, class, console, format

Okay, so I've looked all over this site and a few others (but please let me know if there is a link to a similar question), and I get all the details of how an inventory system should work. My question is coming from a very broad, general perspective. And this is just for a console text RPG. How should I structure my classes for items? What I'm thinking/have so far is something like this:

```
    // Item.h

    class Item {
    public:
        int Id;
        std::string Name;
        bool CanUse, CanEquip;

        virtual void Use();
    }

    class Weapon: public Item {
    public:
        int Attack, Defense, Health; // stat changes when equipped
        void Use() { std::cout << "Can't use\n"; }

    }

    class Sword: public Weapon {
        // constructor defining stat changes for a sword
        // and to define Name = "Sword"
    }
```

So should I be inheriting that many times or is there something easier I could be doing? Eventually, I'll have other various kinds of weapons, but it seems to me that inheriting each of them from `Weapon` is much more cumbersome than some other way I could be doing it?

Perhaps I could have an enumeration or struct within `Weapon` that defines each type of weapon? If I do it like the code above, I would probably actually move the `virtual void Use();` function into a class, `class Consumables: public Item` since those should be the only "usable" things.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help. I have taught myself everything I know with books and online tutorials, so I'm quite inexperienced :)

Comment: Just a note on your naming convention.  Its probably worth using longer more descriptive names.  For example int attackModifier, int uniqueItemId.  Making variables descriptive can save you some time when you comeback in a year and have to edit this code. Another aside you might want an item description so the user can hover an item and get the name and details.

Comment: @user3853544 That's what I have actually done in the code I'm running. I just didn't want to type that stuff out here - to save space. I didn't even know I could do an item description, so that's helpful and cool. Thanks!

Comment: I generally make a limited number of items and go with a description string. Other than a bit more or less damage and reach, a sword is a sword, as far as game mechanics are concerned. I will have a different class if a sword does something unusual like eat souls. Here's an answer I wrote a while back that may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003408/c-determine-if-class-can-use-an-object-text-rpg-game/41006740#41006740

Comment: @user4581301 So in your answer you suggest just making enumeration `types`. I want to be able to say something like `Item* item = new Sword();` and have every sword be the same in stats. Where would I define that? So far, my plan is to make a Sword constructor that defines all of that. Would it be possible to make a switch case in the Item constructor that takes `types` as a parameter and returns a sword pointer?

Comment: `types` was a dodge to make things easier for the OP to manage what classes were allowed to use which item categories. You could use the concept to make an item factory, but it won't scale well as you add more specific items. If you have `Sword` and that's it for swords, you won't have a problem, but when you have a hundred different types of swords and need an enum for each... Yuck.

Comment: Off topic: "I have taught myself everything I know with books" With the right books that's actually a pretty good way to go. The rest is practice and reading more. Read magazines, more books, credible tutorials, good code and even sometimes bad code so you know what not to do.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up deciding to do was this:

```
enum class ItemType {
    Sword,
    Axe,
    Health_potion,
    Helmet,
    Random
}

Item CreateItem(ItemType Names) {
    Item item;
    if (Names == ItemType::Random)
    {
        Names = (ItemType)Rand0toN1(4); // just a function spitting
    }                                  // out a rand number 0 to N-1
    switch (Names)
    {
        case ItemType::Sword:
            item = Item("Sword", 5, 0, 0, 0, false, true, 6);
            break; // constructor Item(Name, attack, defense, health
        case ItemType::Axe:    // maxhealth, canUse, canEquip, slot)
            item = Item("Axe", 3, 1, 0, 0, false, true, 6);
            break;
        case ItemType::Helmet:
            item = Item("Helmet", 0, 3, 0, 1, false, true, 4);
            break;
        case ItemType::Health_potion:
            item = Item("Health Potion", 0, 7, 0, 0, true, false, 0);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    return item;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with doing something like this? Instead of having all of those inherited classes, I now just have the Item class.