# How to refer to instances of a class universally without type codes?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, polymorphism

I was making a text based RPG in which I have an abstract `Item` class. From this `Item` class, I have the classes `Weapon`, `Potion`, `Key`, and `Armor`. The main character class, `Protagonist` uses these items and has a function `doItemEffect(Item*)`. How do I implement `doItemEffect(Item*)` in a way that I refer to all items in universally? To better phrase my problem, if I wasn't clear, here is an example that uses a quite ugly solution.

```
class Protagonist
{
public:
    void doItemEffect(Item* it)
    {
        switch(it->getType()) //<-- The type is an enum class
        {
        case ItemType::WEAPON:
            attackOpponent(it.getAttackPower()); //If it is a weapon it would have this function
            break;
        case ItemType::POTION:
            heal(it.getHealPower()); //If it is a weapon it would have this function
            break;
        case ItemType::KEY:
            //..Code..
            break;
        case ItemType::ARMOR:
            //More Code...
            break;
     }
};
```

And an example of two of the classes `Potion` and `Weapon` (The type of the class is a private variable stored in `Item` with a mutator method `setType()`):

```
class Potion : public Item
{
    int healPower;
public:
    Potion(std::string name, std::string description) : Item(name, description)
    {
        setType(ItemType::POTION);
    }
    //Code
};
```

Weapon:

```
class Weapon : public Item
{
    int attackPower;
public:
    Weapon(std::string name, std::string description) : Item(name, description)
    {
        setType(ItemType::WEAPON);
    }
    //Code
};
```

As you can see, this code relies on an class code and a switch in the `Protagonist` class. Because of this, this doesn't seem very object oriented or polymorphic. Thus, is there a way I could get what subclass a type of Item is, without having to use class codes? Or is there any other solution? The other problem with this snippet above is also that whenever I refer to an item outside of its class, I have to use the same switch statement for each type of item.

Comment: Give `Item` a virtual function, say `virtual void performEffectOn(Protagonist* p) = 0;`. Then have each item implement it accordingly. E.g. `Weapon::performEffectOn(Protagonist* p) { p->attackOpponent(getAttackPower()); }` Finally, `Protagonist::doItemEffect(Item* it)` would simply call `it->performEffectOn(this);`

Comment: This is exactly the sort of problem that polymorphism addresses.

Comment: Very similar to: [C++ Determine if class can use an object - text RPG game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003408/c-determine-if-class-can-use-an-object-text-rpg-game)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is there a way to do this without `Item` knowing about `Protagonist`. My initial solution implemented what you said, but I wanted a solution that would address the problem I am referring to.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is this "problem you are referring to". What's wrong with `Item` knowing about `Protagonist`? Anyway, you might be looking for the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik True, you do make a good point. It's not like the Protagonist is going to be a member anyway, so there won't be a double link. The Protagonist needs to know what to do with the item anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a virtual function `use()` in your `Item` class. Override this function from your derived classes to trigger the various actions (attack, heal, etc.), so that all your subclassed items have an abstract interface to use/apply them.

Comment: That's great and all, but is there a way to do this without `Item` knowing about its owner?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you try rephrasing or giving a more concreting example? The way I see it, if you want your `Item` to mutate the state of your `Protagonist`, it has to 'know' about it.

Comment: You do make a good point, so I will mark this correct as I don't really want to use the Visitor design pattern since there is a much simpler solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use RTTI (e.g. `dynamic_cast<>()`) as an alternative to a dedicated type field:

```
class Protagonist
{
public:
    void doItemEffect(Item* it)
    {
        Potion *potion = dynamic_cast<Potion *>(item);
        Weapon *weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon *>(item);
        if (potion != nullptr) {
            heal(potion->getHealPower());
        }
        else if (weapon != nullptr) {
            attackOpponent(weapon->getAttackPower());
        }
```

or use polymorphism by adding a virtual `effect()` class member function in the abstract `Item` class:

```
class Item {
// ...
public:
    virtual void effect(Protagonist *) = 0;
// ...
};
```

and overriding it in the derived classes:

```
class Potion : public Item
{
// ...
public:
    void effect(Protagonist *) override;
};
```

which has the drawback that your Potion class needs to know that it can be used by a `Protagonist`. To remedy this, [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) is often used. The problem being that C++ does not support double dispatch as a language feature. It can be simulated using the visitor pattern as such:

```
class Weapon;
class Potion;

class DispatchReceiver {
public:
    virtual void effect(Weapon *) = 0;
    virtual void effect(Potion *) = 0;
};

class Item {
// ...
public:
    virtual void effect(DispatchReceiver *) = 0;
// ...
};

class Potion : public Item {
// ...
    virtual void effect(DispatchReceiver *dr) override
    {
        dr->effect(this);
    }
// ...
};

class Weapon : public Item {
// ...
public:
    virtual void effect(DispatchReceiver *dr) override
    {
        dr->effect(this);
    }
// ...
};

class Protagonist : public DispatchReceiver {
// ...
public:
    void effect(Weapon *weapon) override
    {
        attackOpponent(weapon->getAttackPower());
    }
    void effect(Potion *potion) override
    {
        heal(potion->getHealPower());
    }
    void doItemEffect(Item* it)
    {
        it->effect(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: The first option is a horrorshow in the making. It can be made to work but it is so inferior to the second option that I wouldn't even list it.

Comment: @user4581301 I would agree that using some kind of switching on type is most often an indication of a suboptimal design. But then again, there are exceptions to this rule. In this case it would indeed hint at a bad design, because there are viable design alternatives, but I included it for didactical reasons (type field -> RTTI switch -> simple polymorphism -> double dispatch).

Comment: It looks to me like both of your methods are effectively manually implementing *virtual dispatch*. Why doesn't the weapon simply call `attack()` and the `Potion` call `heal()`? You have already selected for type at that point through the virtual function call. No need to pass that on to another dispatcher of your own making. The `Protagonist` knows whether or not it can use a potion or a weapon.

Comment: @Galik Items would need to know about `attack()` and `heal()` which are supposedly class member functions of `Protagonist`. There could be other `DispatchReceiver`s though, like `class Antagonist : public DispatchReceiver { ... };`. `Item`s don't need to know about any of their specifics using double dispatch as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Have a list of item types

```
template<class...Types>
struct type_list_t{};

using Items=type_list_t<Potion, Weapon, etc>;
```

this replaces your enum.  You can write get index of type, and get type from (compile time) index.  You can even write what I call a magic switch, mapping runtime (bounded) index to a compile time type via continuation passing style.

Next add a visit method to `Item`.  It takes a index into the type list and then static casts this to the type of the child, then invokes a passed-in callback with the result of the cast.

Write function overloads that look like this:

```
void use_item( Protagonist*, Potion* );
void use_item( Protagonist*, Weapon* );
```

Then dispatch to it using visit in Protagonist.

Now you can simplify this by using a pre written `variant`.

```
template<class Base, class...Ts>
struct poly_variant:boost::variant<Ts...>{
  using boost::variant<Ts...>::variant;
  Base& base();
  Base const& base() const;
};
```

now you can visit in Protagonist.  A variant of this can be used if you want to make the storage be a pointer (or a smart pointer).

Write `base()` via apply visitor.